# Mobile Website NavBar Logo Left Margin

Tags: feature-request, design, mobile-web

I was viewing the mobile website of Stack Overflow and noticed that the Logo on the top, along with the hamburger, needs some margin at its left as it is sticking to the edge of the screen.

[image: ScreenShot]

I figured out that the following changes in the Site's CSS would probably help:

```
a.topbar-icon.js-site-switcher-button.icon-site-switcher-bubble{
    left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I see you haven't marked this as a bug, but a feature request. Could you explain why you desire to have a larger menu button? I personally like the small one, it takes less space and still is clear to me. As a bug, I would guess it's [meta-tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: I've always wondered if that was intentional or not.

Comment: FWIW, this is actually quite common and is probably intentional.